# PHP jQuery passing values with multiple words

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery that filters some items displayed in a query by color.

The problem comes with colors such as "Blue Navy". Apparently the jQuery doesn't pass the two words or something. When I echo results of the `_GET` values I never get anything when a 2 word color has been passed, while I do get my values for one-word colors.

Any idea of why this happens?

Here are my codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
        $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
        var color = $(this).val();
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color,function(){
            $(".indexMain").fadeIn(slow);

            })
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
        }
        else 
            {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
$(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php');
                        $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
            }
        });
    });

$color = $_GET['color'];

$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
        $items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
```

Comment: Try `var color = $(this).val().toString().replace(' ', '-');`

Comment: @PitaJ, shouldn't it be `+` instead of `-` ? Also, `.val()` returns a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is a GET request, the value is appended to the querystring, and a querystring can not contain regular spaces.

You need to url encode the value before using it in the querystring:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            var color = encodeURI(this.value);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color=' + color, function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn(slow);
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});

$color = $_GET['color'];

$items = $con - > prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
$items - > bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);​
```

the `$_GET` superglobal should be automatically url decoded back in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = $(this).val().replace(/ /g, '+');
```

This will work in your case, but a better way is to use encodeURI as explained by adenneo